# Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome Desktop: Does anynody knows how to start a program from terminal using "Dedicated Graphics Card"?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, 20.04, nvidia-prime

I have hopefully a quick question that I haven't been able to resolve:

I installed Ubuntu 20.04, (great distro by the way).
I'm running the NVIDIA driver with the "on demand" profile on the prime settings.

All I have to do is right click on the Icon of the program and choose "Launch using dedicated Graphics Card", and all is well. It runs smoothly. If I Don't do it this way, the performance is "choppy" because it uses the Intel graphics card instead of the NVIDIA.

(BTW, if I put the driver on "performance" mode on the PRIME profiles. The programs get the Intel card no matter what, I don't know why that is, but I'm working fine with the "on demand" mode.

However.... this is my question:

I have a couple programs like Meshroom that do not use and installer or package, and runs directly with a binary in the terminal.

But when I execute it, it always get the Intel graphics card".

**Do you know what line (Or lines in a little script) do I need to put on the command line to execute the command with Dedicated graphics support?**

I've been looking around and the methods for Ubuntu 16 and 18 like putting "DRI_PRIME=1" in front of the command don't seem to work with this new release.

Thanks a lot.
I would really appreciate your answers, insight or suggestions.  :)

Have a great day. Stay safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <app to execute>
```

As far as I know, it was usefull on 19.10 for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is also for others to know, that the proposal of @"Noctis" https://askubuntu.com/users/817301/noctis works perfectly in Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome Desktop with Wayland, too.